Are there any benefits to having ferrite cores integrated into HDMI cables?
Although many do not, some HDMI cables have a ferrite core integrated near one or both ends.
Are there any benefits to having ferrite cores integrated into HDMI cables?
I read these related Super User QAs:

Does the presence or size of the ferrite bead cylinder on my USB cable affect its performance?
How to deal with HDMI cable interference?

It appears that there may be some benefits for lower quality USB cables, but there is little information regarding HDMI cables.
The closest I read is when Mokubai mentioned, when referring to a group of cables that includes HDMI cables:

"Ferrite may well attenuate signals in those ranges and I have not seen any cables with ferrite fitted on them."

It seems a little ambiguous if Mokubai is considering the possible signal attenuation a good or bad quality. If I'm reading that statement correctly, it seems like Mokubai is perhaps hypothesizing it would be bad, and that's why they haven't seen HDMI cables with ferrite cores.
But HDMI cables with integrated ferrite cores are reasonably common (I happen to be looking at a couple right now), and I'm wondering what are the benefits, if any, of using them?

Most, if not all, quality HDMI cables don't have ferrite cores - this creates the inference lower end HDMI cables have PCBs on either end of the cable with PCB components that don't handle noise adequately. MonoPrice has always created high quality cables and none of their HDMI cables have ferrite cores, neither do massively overpriced Monster cables. There's also three different types of HDMI cables, and while AOC cables wouldn't apply, I don't recall seeing ferrite cores on any of the other two types with quality cables.

Ferrite cores effectively add some level of resistance to voltage changes within the cable, effectively reducing common mode noise in the cable. They are generally more effective at particular frequencies than others due to core size, material and construction.
Ferrites are generally chosen to limit particular kinds of noise in cables, and the most common unwanted noise in modern computers will be the various switch mode power supplies which sluice current back and forth through an inductor at anywhere between 100kHz and several MHz. That noise can be picked up by pretty much every wire in a system or transferred through any device connected to that power supply.
Many digital signals are much faster than that so a well chosen ferrite can add a high level of noise suppression at chosen frequencies while affecting other frequencies to a far lower degree.
Ferrite cores on an HDMI cable will reduce leaked noise from power supplies in the computer and monitor, in theory better isolating their supplies from each other and allowing less interference on the remaining cable runs. You should end up with less noise both inside the computer and monitor, as they are receiving less noise from each other, and the signal should be cleaner as it isn't reacting as much to noise while in the cable.
A ferrite will have some effect on almost all signals, but depending on the types and speeds of signals it may not be important.
Not all applications or devices will need ferrites. Some devices may implement an equivalent in the port hardware, or work around it in another way, and so not need or want a cable with ferrites in it.

Most, if not all, quality HDMI cables don't have ferrite cores - this creates the inference lower end HDMI cables have PCBs on either end of the cable with PCB components that don't handle noise adequately. MonoPrice has always created high quality cables and none of their HDMI cables have ferrite cores, neither do massively overpriced Monster cables. There's also three different types of HDMI cables, and while AOC cables wouldn't apply, I don't recall seeing ferrite cores on any of the other two types with quality cables.

(Cont'd...) While HDMI cables are more widely used in home theater than with PCs, it would be interesting to see independent testing of HDMI cables with a ferrite core on and off compared to a high quality cable (such as this one), and whether any picture and audio quality degradation can be detected by the eyes and ears, as well as passed through an oscilloscope to see at the frequency level. (Quality HDMI cables from MonoPrice are less expensive than budget cables at big box stores - it's why I've recommended MonoPrice for over a decade)

Thanks for your quality answer.  It's clear to me except the very last phrase, where you used the words: "not need or want".  The "not need" part makes sense to me.  The "not ... want" part, to me, implies it is undesirable in the cases you mentioned.  I don't think that's what you meant to convey, but can you clarify, and perhaps edit if you think that's appropriate?

@EndAntisemiticHate Perhaps it would be better written as "neither need nor want"... basically with some things you might not need certain things but you might still want them and in others you might not need them and not want them either. It is more trying to judge whether there is no need but the desire is beneficial or harmful and with ferrites you could attenuate a marginal signal slightly so that the port filtering causes issues, so you wouldn't want it at all, or it might not do anything in which case you might want it for placebo effect.

Thanks for the clarification.  When you mention "marginal signal", in reference to HDMI signals, would those pretty much only be caused by faulty hardware or excessively long cable runs?

I could be wrong but, adding a ferrite core on an HDMI cable will reduce the EMI (electromagnetic interference) on the cable (can be useful for long cables >2m).
But it won't do anything to the data since HDMI transmits digital signals so if the data transmission is successful (with or without ferrite core), the video and audio quality remain perfect.
EDIT: As JW0914 mentioned in the comments, in the context of a home theater the amount of EMI should be very limited, and as far as I know, most of HDMI cables are shielded with at least one layer.
Maybe adding ferrite core can help if you have an HDMI cable running in a wall with a power cable near it, but again as JW0914 says, it is not a good practice to put data lines near power cables.

Where would the EMI be coming from on home theater equipment (the vast majority of HDMI cables are used in home theater)? Most TVs have a wide separation of the PSU PCB from the video board PCB, and with a PC case, simple cable management inside the case can ensure all power cables from the PSU are kept far away from video cards and the motherboard (good practice regardless since SATA cables sometimes have issues when power cables are routed close to them).

@JW0914 When you mention "wide separation" of the PSU and video board PCBs, are you only referring to physical separation?

I am - most TVs have their PSUs far away from video board PCB, with the larger the TV, the wider the separation. Home theater receivers often do the same thing, with the PSU on the bottom of the unit and the video board almost directly below the top of the unit. If anything was going to produce noise it would be massive amplifiers in receivers that far exceed any type of amplifier in a TV or PC, yet they don't.

(I missed something) For length, it's all about the PCB in either end of the cable - AFAIK signal degradation occurs from lacking the requisite amount of amperage to continue pushing the signal (AFAIK a ferrite core won't help with that). Non-AOC HDMI cables can be made in lengths up to 100ft for 4K, albeit I would opt for a fiber optic AOC cable for the ~$120 price. With active sync cables, it's point to point, couplers can't be used. Low voltage next to AC allows the potential for a screw to penetrate one to the other.
